# AIR: considering the MacOSX menubar?

Tags: air

i wonder how i can set the screenBounds of my App to regard the MacOSX Menubar on top of the screen and the Dock.

If i'm using the normal screenBounds method in AS3, the screenBounds values always get the REAL screenBounds (0,0 and total width of the screen)...however i would like to just get the available space on the desktop (minus dock, menubar or taskbar on windows)???

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Screen.visibleBounds`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Screen.html#visibleBounds) claims to take menus and docks into account.